# Unexpected ReplaceAll behavior with NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

I ran into some unexpected behavior using ReplaceAll with an equation of motion using NSolve (or Solve, also). First solving for the initial velocity v0:

`In[67]:= Clear[v0, v, dist, t, a, vInit, vFinal]
In[68]:= dist = Quantity[700, "Meters"]
Out[68]= Quantity[700, "Meters"]
In[69]:= t = Quantity[30, "Seconds"]
Out[69]= Quantity[30, "Seconds"]
In[70]:= a = Quantity[.05, "Meters per second^2"]
Out[70]= Quantity[0.05, ("Meters")/("Seconds")^2]
In[79]:= vInit = NSolve[dist == v0*t + 1/2 a*t^2, v0]
Out[79]= {{v0 -> Quantity[22.5833, ("Meters")/("Seconds")]}}`

Then I use ReplaceAll to substitute the v0 solution in the equation to solve for vFinal.  However, in this case, I get an error and null results:

```
In[80]:= vFinal =  NSolve[{a (dist) == 1/2 (v^2 - v0^2), v >= 0}, v] /. vInit

During evaluation of In[80]:= NSolve::ratnz: NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

Out[80]= {{}}
```

If I change the vInit NSolve command to output a value for vInit instead of a rule, NSolve then successfully calculates vFinal, as follows:

```
In[81]:= vInit = v0 /. NSolve[dist == v0*t + 1/2 a*t^2, v0]   
Out[81]= {Quantity[22.5833, ("Meters")/("Seconds")]}
In[82]:= vFinal = NSolve[{a (dist) == 1/2 (v^2 - vInit^2), v >= 0}, v]    
Out[82]= {{v -> Quantity[24.0833, ("Meters")/("Seconds")]}}
```

The error only occurs if I constrain the NSolve equation with v>=0.  If I leave out this constraint, NSolve works correctly, generating both solutions to the equation:

```
In[88]:= vFinal = NSolve[a (dist) == 1/2 (v^2 - v0^2), v] /. vInit
Out[88]= {{{v -> Quantity[-24.0833, ("Meters")/("Seconds")]}, {v -> 
    Quantity[24.0833, ("Meters")/("Seconds")]}}}
```

As I said, I've used ReplaceAll for other similar calculations with no problem.  This is the first time ReplaceAll hasn't worked as I expected.  Am I misusing ReplaceAll for these type operations, or is this abnormal behavior for ReplaceAll and NSolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear[v0, v, dist, t, a, vInit, vFinal];
dist = Quantity[700, "Meters"];
t = Quantity[30, "Seconds"];
a = Quantity[.05, "Meters per second^2"];
vInit = NSolve[dist == v0*t + 1/2 a*t^2, v0][[1]]
```

> {v0 -> Quantity[22.5833, ("Meters")/("Seconds")]}

Put the `ReplaceAll` inside of the `NSolve` (in both instances you could use `Solve` rather than `NSolve`).

```
vFinal = NSolve[{a dist == 1/2 (v^2 - v0^2) /. vInit, v >= 0}, v][[1]]
```

> {v -> Quantity[24.0833, ("Meters")/("Seconds")]}

Comment: thanks for the response.  However, when I do that, I get the following error:  `NSolve::naqs: {275.(m)^2\[NegativeMediumSpace]/(s)^2==1/2 (v^2+-1083.51(m)^2\[NegativeMediumSpace]/(s)^2)}&&v>=0 is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities. >>`

Comment: I just copied the code from my post and it executed without a problem. I ran the code on Mma v10.1 with MacOS 10.10.3. Have you tried with a fresh kernel?

Comment: My original code did not have a Part specification in the calculation of vInit (since it only produces a single value for vInit) nor in vFinal (since the v>=0 constraint forces only the positive solution).  When I add `[[1]]` at the end of the vInit line as you did, I don't get the error in the calculation of vFinal (even if I don't also use `[[1]]` in the vFinal line). While that answers the original question, it begs another: why is the part specification in vInit necessary for a calculation that only produces a single value?

Comment: Your original code doesn't produce a single value, it produces a `List` containing a single `List` containing a single rule. Using this with the `ReplaceAll` results in a `List` structure different from the form {eqn, constraint} needed as the argument to `Solve`.

Comment: That all makes sense now. Thank you for your help